# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling pushViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, exc-bad-access, uiactionsheet

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UITabBarController`.

When I'm calling

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

there is no problem.

But, when I'm calling the same line from inside a `UIActionSheetDelegate`, for example:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

It seems that calling this line from a different thread causing this issue.

How can I prevent this `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` issue?

(notice that myViewController is NOT nil, or something like that)

thanks!

Comment: Can you please post all the code you have for actionSheet: clickedButtonAtIndex so we can better assist you with your problem?

Comment: When you have this error have you opened the debbuger (gdb) to focus which is the instruction that causes this error? Could you post the detail here please?

Comment: calling to:
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

causing the error

Comment: Have you try to print the navigationController reference like that NSLog(@"%@",[self navigationController]);? It may be null.

Answer (score 5):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is thrown when you try to access a released object, and `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` is called on the main thread, after the action sheet is dismissed, so I'm guessing what's pointed by `myViewController` is released.

It doesn't have to be `nil`, in fact, that's the problem. The object pointed is released, but the pointer is not `nil`.

Comment: tnx.

The UIActionSheet is called from within a class called: MainRootViewController

myViewController is a member in this class.

The full code is:

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 myViewController = [[myViewController alloc] init];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES]; 
}

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and mine was that I did not assine the member varible with self when I alloced it.

This causeed a problem: (myTestViewController is the class member)

```
TestViewController* test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    myTestViewController = testViewController;
    [testViewController release];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:myTestViewController animated:YES];
```

But when I change and assied the class member with self it worked.

```
TestViewController* test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    self.myTestViewController = testViewController;
    [testViewController release];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:myTestViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The way I fixed it was by removing `self.navigationController.delegate = self;` from my pushed view controller.

Answer (score 0):

tnx.

The UIActionSheet is called from within a class called: MainRootViewController

myViewController is a member in this class (MainRootViewController).

The full code is:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { 

myViewController = [[myViewController alloc] init];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

 }
```

Comment: are you sure this is your real code? because you're calling alloc on a pointer, not a class.

Comment: no, my mistake. the line is:
myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];